# Handling time out in firebase

Tags: android, firebase

I am trying to implement registration using firebase, but somehow when connection breaks,`onCancelled()` is not getting called.I tried working with `onDisconnect()` but no success.Finally i landed up calling a php wrapper for firebase and got rid of this problem.The wrapper i used is https://github.com/ktamas77/firebase-php. Is this wrong way of implementing because there are 2 server calls(->php->firebase) involved which will eventually make my application slow or there is an alternate to time out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really explore why your onDisconnect() is not working as it's reliable and works well.

If you really want to monitor your connection status, look into the .info/connected special location in Firebase.

[How to build a user presence system](http://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html)

[Managing Presence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/offline-capabilities#section-presence)

about 1/2 way down in the Detecting Connection State section.

We have a singleton that monitors connection status and when the connection is lost all of our classes are notified so they can take appropriate action.